# Maven Compile Failed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spigot

i got a maven compile problem after i reinstalled the windows.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project helium: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project helium: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.0/maven-compiler-plugin-3.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-utils/0.1/maven-shared-utils-0.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-incremental/1.0/maven-shared-incremental-1.0.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.0/plexus-compiler-api-2.0.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/2.0/plexus-compiler-manager-2.0.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/gukka/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/cli/CommandLineException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.get (AbstractMap.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.DefaultCompilerManager.getCompiler (DefaultCompilerManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$CycleActivator.onProvision (BeanScheduler.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:120)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get (ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get (SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.get (AbstractMap.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.DefaultCompilerManager.getCompiler (DefaultCompilerManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :helium

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the error with -X flag

mvn -v:

Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_345, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.345.1-hotspot\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: I would really need the pom.xml if I was going to help with this.

Comment: there you go https://pastebin.com/Qw4e0q9B

Comment: just started looking at this and you have a really screwed up pom.xml! It should not look like this if you're making Spigot/Paper plugins on IntelliJ. No wonder you're having problems lol!